# Relation not exist using psqlto restore PostgreSQL dump

Tags: database, postgresql, command-line, syntax-error

I tried to restore the following file to a database in PostgreSQL 9.

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 9.5.10
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 9.5.10

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET search_path = xml, pg_catalog;

--
-- Data for Name: t_us_sir_flag; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: xml; Owner: -
--

COPY t_us_sir_flag (us_sir_flag_id, publication_id, modified_load_id, status, content) FROM stdin;
\.


--
-- Name: t_us_sir_flag_us_sir_flag_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE SET; Schema: xml; Owner: -
--

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('t_us_sir_flag_us_sir_flag_id_seq', 1, false);


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Here is the code I usded along with the error information.
[image]

Can anyone please let me know how to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to create the table before you can `COPY` into it.

Whoever created the dump file used the `--data-only` option of `pg_dump`, so that the table definition, constraints and indexes are not included in the dump.